# Non-capturing group inside a named group

Tags: python, regex

I'm working with a Python regex for extracting time durations in '2h30m' format.
I run into an issue where non-capturing groups  (`(?:...)`) are getting captured inside named groups.

e.g. matching `2h30m` against:

```
(?P<hours>\d+(?:h))?(?P<minutes>\d+(?:m))?
```

would match `{'hours': '2h', 'minutes': '30m'}`, and not `2` and `30`.

The workaround would be to use a positive lookahead assertions (`(?=...)`), but this doesn't update the state of the regex FSM so we have to repeat the `h`, `m` suffixes:

```
(?P<hours>\d+(?=h))?h?(?P<minutes>\d+(?=m))?m?
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are `h`and `m` really optional? A regex that can match an unanchored empty string is a bad practice.

Comment: Non-capturing groups don't "anti-capture" what they match and remove them from outer groups; they're just a way to group things together so you can apply quantifiers to them.

Comment: @stribizhev: The regex should match '5h', '5m' and '5h5m'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Non-capturing groups don't "anti-capture" what they match and remove them from outer groups. They're just a way to group things together so you can apply quantifiers to them.

To get the effect you want, you can rearrange the groups to put the non-capturing groups outside the capturing groups:

```
(?:(?P<hours>\d+)h)?(?:(?P<minutes>\d+)m)?
```